# Actionscript 3 - Facebook loading User Image from Graph API

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air

Im using Facebook Graph API to login to Facebook in my App, but after onLogin is fired i get the user image but I'm trying to load the image. But the image is not loading

Could someone advise please?

Code is below:

```
package  {


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.CameraUI;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;  
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;
import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.*;  

public class test extends MovieClip {

    var webView:StageWebView;
    var vidCon:Video = new Video();
    const APP_ID:String = "299210093578823";
    var extendedPermissions:Array = ["publish_stream","user_about_me"];
    var user:User;
    var loader:Loader;

    public function test() {
        //Security.allowDomain("*");
        //Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit, "CAACEdEose0cBAMy735qLgTobu9YZB1Xas0l5NS5BF02NyXTeDoPjnh1vZBel1LQGdxZA2v4AKOGVqWDSUVOthn3accqiXzyMgrZAqMwKHNZB2Cu27Fzn70WWxc6rvuixgb4bgZAiat3yKtPccRxSFCPPW7CTKbIN6ctFCBzGmw3oeNfhZAZBktPONdhJ2R2SGYxHCDKbUuTZCtwZDZD");                           
        btn_fb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onFBLoginClick);


    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        // Generally good practice to remove this listener from the object now because it stops addedToStageHandler from being called again if the object is removed and added back to the stage or display list.

        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        //stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        stage.stageWidth = Math.max(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        stage.stageHeight = Math.min(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);

        var yBotButton = stage.stageWidth - botButton.height;
        //botButton.y = yBotButton;


    }




    private function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        setTimeout(startOnINit, 3000, success);

    }

    public function startOnINit()
    {
        if (arguments[0])
        { 
            trace(JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));
            trace("Already logged in");
            btn_fb.visible = false;
        }
        else
        {  
            //btn.enabled = true;
            trace("Not logged in-");
        }

        trans.visible = false;
    }

    private function onFBLoginClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("ddddd");     
        FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,this.stage, extendedPermissions,getWebView());
    }

    private function getWebView():StageWebView 
    { 
        if(webView) webView.dispose();

        webView = new StageWebView();
        webView.stage=this.stage;
        webView.assignFocus();

        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        return webView;
    }

    public function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        trace("fjfjfj");
        trace(JSON.stringify(success));
        if (success)
        {
            btn_fb.visible = false;
            setupUserLoginProfile(success);
            trace("Logged In\n");
        }
        else
        {        
            trace("Login Failed\n");
        }
    }

    public function setupUserLoginProfile(userProfile:Object)
    {
        trace("111111111111");
        var imageUrl = Facebook.getImageUrl(userProfile.user.id); 
        trace(userProfile.user.link);
        trace(imageUrl);

        user = new User(imageUrl);

        var shape1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        shape1.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc,1); 
        shape1.graphics.drawRect(0,0,320,140);     
        shape1.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(shape1);

        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("https://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("https://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");

        trace("sss" + user.userImage);

        loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest(user.userImage));
        shape1.addChild(loader);
        loader.x=25;
        loader.y=25;
        loader.width = 80;
        loader.height = 80;

    }



}

}
```

### MODIFIED

I get an error in the try catch syntax

> Error: [strict] Ignoring policy file at
>   http://profile.cc.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml due to incorrect syntax. 
>   See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.
>
> SecurityError: Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access
>   this feature.

```
package  {


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.CameraUI;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;  
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;
import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.*;  

public class test extends MovieClip {

    var webView:StageWebView;
    var vidCon:Video = new Video();
    const APP_ID:String = "299210093578823";
    var extendedPermissions:Array = ["publish_stream","user_about_me"];
    var user:User;
    var loader:Loader;

    public function test() {
        //Security.allowDomain("*");
        //Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit, "CAACEdEose0cBAMy735qLgTobu9YZB1Xas0l5NS5BF02NyXTeDoPjnh1vZBel1LQGdxZA2v4AKOGVqWDSUVOthn3accqiXzyMgrZAqMwKHNZB2Cu27Fzn70WWxc6rvuixgb4bgZAiat3yKtPccRxSFCPPW7CTKbIN6ctFCBzGmw3oeNfhZAZBktPONdhJ2R2SGYxHCDKbUuTZCtwZDZD");                           
        btn_fb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onFBLoginClick);


    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        // Generally good practice to remove this listener from the object now because it stops addedToStageHandler from being called again if the object is removed and added back to the stage or display list.

        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        //stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        stage.stageWidth = Math.max(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        stage.stageHeight = Math.min(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);

        var yBotButton = stage.stageWidth - botButton.height;
        //botButton.y = yBotButton;


    }




    private function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        setTimeout(startOnINit, 3000, success);

    }

    public function startOnINit()
    {
        if (arguments[0])
        { 
            trace(JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));
            trace("Already logged in");
            btn_fb.visible = false;
        }
        else
        {  
            //btn.enabled = true;
            trace("Not logged in-");
        }

        trans.visible = false;
    }

    private function onFBLoginClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("ddddd");     
        FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,this.stage, extendedPermissions,getWebView());
    }

    private function getWebView():StageWebView 
    { 
        if(webView) webView.dispose();

        webView = new StageWebView();
        webView.stage=this.stage;
        webView.assignFocus();

        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        return webView;
    }

    public function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        trace("fjfjfj");
        trace(JSON.stringify(success));
        if (success)
        {
            btn_fb.visible = false;
            setupUserLoginProfile(success);
            trace("Logged In\n");
        }
        else
        {        
            trace("Login Failed\n");
        }
    }

    public function setupUserLoginProfile(userProfile:Object)
    {
        trace("111111111111");
        var imageUrl = Facebook.getImageUrl(userProfile.user.id); 
        trace(userProfile.user.link);
        trace(imageUrl);

        user = new User(imageUrl);

        var shape1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        shape1.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc,1); 
        shape1.graphics.drawRect(0,0,320,140);     
        shape1.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(shape1);

        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("https://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("https://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.loadPolicyFile('http://profile.cc.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml');
        Security.loadPolicyFile('https://profile.cc.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml');
        Security.loadPolicyFile('http://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml');
        Security.loadPolicyFile('https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml');
        Security.loadPolicyFile('http://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml');
        Security.loadPolicyFile('https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml');
        try {              
            Security.allowDomain("*");
            Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        }
        catch(error:Error){
            trace(error);
        }


        trace("sss" + user.userImage);

        loader = new Loader();
        loader.load(new URLRequest(user.userImage));
        shape1.addChild(loader);
        loader.x=25;
        loader.y=25;
        loader.width = 80;
        loader.height = 80;
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);

    }

    function loadingError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("There has been an error loading the image. The server may be busy. Refresh the page and try again.");
    }

    function doneLoad(e:Event):void {
        trace("doneload");
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: In AS3 there's no such thing as "the image is not loading", it either loads or it return an IOError but in any case you get back information as to what's going on. So make the effort to report what's really happening. As long as you stick with "the image is not loading" you'll very likely not get any help.

Comment: @BotMaster, i don't get an IOError but i get this in the console Warning: Ignoring 'secure' attribute in policy file from http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml.  The 'secure' attribute is only permitted in HTTPS and socket policy files.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for details.

Warning: Ignoring 'secure' attribute in policy file from http://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml.  The 'secure' attribute is only permitted in HTTPS and socket policy files.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to load the bitmap then append the bitmap:

Code is below:

```
package  {


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.CameraUI;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;  
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;
import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.*;  
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

public class test extends MovieClip {

    var webView:StageWebView;
    var vidCon:Video = new Video();
    const APP_ID:String = "299210093578823";
    var extendedPermissions:Array = ["publish_stream","user_about_me"];
    var user:User;
    var loader:Loader;
    var shape1:MovieClip;

    public function test() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit, "CAACEdEose0cBAMy735qLgTobu9YZB1Xas0l5NS5BF02NyXTeDoPjnh1vZBel1LQGdxZA2v4AKOGVqWDSUVOthn3accqiXzyMgrZAqMwKHNZB2Cu27Fzn70WWxc6rvuixgb4bgZAiat3yKtPccRxSFCPPW7CTKbIN6ctFCBzGmw3oeNfhZAZBktPONdhJ2R2SGYxHCDKbUuTZCtwZDZD");                           
        btn_fb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onFBLoginClick);


    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        // Generally good practice to remove this listener from the object now because it stops addedToStageHandler from being called again if the object is removed and added back to the stage or display list.

        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        //stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

        stage.stageWidth = Math.max(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);
        stage.stageHeight = Math.min(stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight);

        var yBotButton = stage.stageWidth - botButton.height;
        //botButton.y = yBotButton;


    }




    private function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        setTimeout(startOnINit, 3000, success);

    }

    public function startOnINit()
    {
        if (arguments[0])
        { 
            trace(JSON.stringify(arguments[0]));
            trace("Already logged in");
            btn_fb.visible = false;
        }
        else
        {  
            //btn.enabled = true;
            trace("Not logged in-");
        }

        trans.visible = false;
    }

    private function onFBLoginClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace("ddddd");     
        FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,this.stage, extendedPermissions,getWebView());
    }

    private function getWebView():StageWebView 
    { 
        if(webView) webView.dispose();

        webView = new StageWebView();
        webView.stage=this.stage;
        webView.assignFocus();

        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        return webView;
    }

    public function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void
    {
        trace("fjfjfj");
        trace(JSON.stringify(success));
        if (success)
        {
            btn_fb.visible = false;
            setupUserLoginProfile(success);
            trace("Logged In\n");
        }
        else
        {        
            trace("Login Failed\n");
        }
    }

    public function setupUserLoginProfile(userProfile:Object)
    {
        trace("111111111111");
        var imageUrl = Facebook.getImageUrl(userProfile.user.id); 
        trace(userProfile.user.link);
        trace(imageUrl);

        user = new User(imageUrl);

        shape1 = new MovieClip();
        shape1.graphics.beginFill(0xcccccc,1); 
        shape1.graphics.drawRect(0,0,320,140);     
        shape1.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(shape1);




        trace("sss" + user.userImage);

        loadPic();

    }

    function loadingError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("There has been an error loading the image. The server may be busy. Refresh the page and try again.");
    }

    function loadPic():void{
        loader = new Loader(); 
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);
        var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
        context.checkPolicyFile = true;
        context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/crossdomain.xml");
        try {              
            Security.allowDomain("*");
            Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        }
        catch(error:Error){
            trace(error);
        }
        loader.load(new URLRequest("https://graph.facebook.com/654358964644178/picture?type=normal"),context);
        loader.x=25;
        loader.y=25;
        loader.width = 80;
        loader.height = 80;
        //shape1.addChild(loader); 
    }


    function doneLoad(e:Event):void {
        trace("doneload");
        var bm:Bitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap;
        bm.smoothing = true;
        bm.x = 10;
        bm.y = 10;
        bm.width = 80;
        bm.height = 80;


        shape1.addChild(bm);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError); 

        loader = null;
    }

}

}
```